# SQL Developer - CASE statement with criteria

Tags: sql, case, peoplesoft

Trying to write a sql statement for Peoplesoft.

My current statement "works" but the output is incorrect.  Here is the sql:

```
SELECT
A.EMPLID, 
A.DEPTID, 
A.LOCATION, 
A.PAYGROUP, 
A.STD_HOURS, 
A.ANNUAL_RT, 
A.COMPRATE, 
SUM(case b.comp_ratecd when 'NAANNL' then b.comprate  else 0 end) AS NAANNL,
sum(case b.comp_ratecd when 'NAHRLY' then b.comprate else 0 end) as NAHRLY,
sum(case C.ERNCD when '007' then (C.HOURLY_RT + C.OTH_PAY) else 0 end) as BASEFTO,
sum(case C.ERNCD when '013' then (C.HOURLY_RT + C.OTH_PAY) else 0 end) as DEFCOMP
FROM PS_JOB A
    ,PS_COMPENSATION B
    ,ps_addl_pay_data C
WHERE A.EFFDT = 
(SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB A_ED 
 WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID 
 AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ED.EMPL_RCD 
 AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE) 
AND A.EFFSEQ = 
(SELECT MAX(A_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_JOB A_ES 
 WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ES.EMPLID 
 AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ES.EMPL_RCD 
 AND A.EFFDT = A_ES.EFFDT) 
AND A.EMPL_STATUS = 'A' 
AND A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID 
AND A.EMPL_RCD = B.EMPL_RCD 
AND A.EFFSEQ = B.EFFSEQ 
AND B.EFFDT = A.EFFDT 
AND A.EMPLID = C.EMPLID (+)
AND A.EMPL_RCD = C.EMPL_RCD (+)
group by A.EMPLID , A.DEPTID, A.LOCATION, A.PAYGROUP, A.STD_HOURS, A.ANNUAL_RT, A.COMPRATE
ORDER BY 1 ;
```

The issue is that when there are 2 or more rows in c.addl_pay_data, the amount under the NAANNL and NAHRLY columns is being multiplied by the number of rows in addl_pay_data.

I would appreciate any help that would tell me how to write this so that when the count of erncd from addl_pay_data is > 0, then take the comprate from compensation and divide by the count erncd.  If the count is = 0, then just list the comprate from compensation.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to sum two different tables over a join. Instead you should do the aggregation for each child table *separately* in a subquery, then join over the result:

```
SELECT
    A.EMPLID, 
    A.DEPTID, 
    A.LOCATION, 
    A.PAYGROUP, 
    A.STD_HOURS, 
    A.ANNUAL_RT, 
    A.COMPRATE, 
    b.NAANNL, b.NAHRLY, c.BASEFTO, c.DEFCOMP
FROM PS_JOB A
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM(case b.comp_ratecd when 'NAANNL' then b.comprate  else 0 end) AS NAANNL,
       sum(case b.comp_ratecd when 'NAHRLY' then b.comprate else 0 end) as NAHRLY,
       EFFDT, EMPL_RCD, EFFSEQ, EMPLID
    FROM PS_COMPENSATION B
    GROUP BY EFFDT, EMPL_RCD, EFFSEQ, EMPLID
) AS B
ON A.EMPLID = B.EMPLID 
AND A.EMPL_RCD = B.EMPL_RCD 
AND A.EFFSEQ = B.EFFSEQ 
AND B.EFFDT = A.EFFDT 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT sum(case C.ERNCD when '007' then (C.HOURLY_RT + C.OTH_PAY) else 0 end) as BASEFTO,
        sum(case C.ERNCD when '013' then (C.HOURLY_RT + C.OTH_PAY) else 0 end) as DEFCOMP,
        EMPLID, EMPL_RCD
    FROM ps_addl_pay_data C
    GROUP BY EMPLID, EMPL_RCD
) AS C
ON A.EMPLID = C.EMPLID (+)
AND A.EMPL_RCD = C.EMPL_RCD (+)
WHERE A.EFFDT = 
(SELECT MAX(A_ED.EFFDT) FROM PS_JOB A_ED 
 WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ED.EMPLID 
 AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ED.EMPL_RCD 
 AND A_ED.EFFDT <= SYSDATE) 
AND A.EFFSEQ = 
(SELECT MAX(A_ES.EFFSEQ) FROM PS_JOB A_ES 
 WHERE A.EMPLID = A_ES.EMPLID 
 AND A.EMPL_RCD = A_ES.EMPL_RCD 
 AND A.EFFDT = A_ES.EFFDT) 
AND A.EMPL_STATUS = 'A' 
group by A.EMPLID , A.DEPTID, A.LOCATION, A.PAYGROUP, A.STD_HOURS, A.ANNUAL_RT, A.COMPRATE
ORDER BY 1 ;
```